# Switched to BigInteger and progam does not run any more

Tags: java, biginteger

So right I was creating a program that made palindromic numbers based on [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/comments/38yy9s/20150608_challenge_218_easy_making_numbers/) project. My program would work for the smaller numbers, but integer can only compute a small amount of numbers, so I changed necessary integers to BigInteger(). After doing this Ive ran into some problems that Im not really sure of. Would anyone have any advice as to how to make this work?

```
public class Main {
public static final boolean DEBUG = false;

public static void main(String[] args) {       
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //gets the number from the console
    int number = input.nextInt();
    if(DEBUG) System.out.println("Got your number!");
    if(DEBUG) System.out.println("Bout to makePalendrome!");

    makePalendrome(number);   
}


public static boolean isPalendrome(BigInteger number){
    String numberString = number.toString();

    for(int i = 0; i < numberString.length(); i++){
        if(numberString.charAt(i) != numberString.charAt(numberString.length() - 1 - i)) return false;   
    }       
    return true;
}


public static void makePalendrome(int input){
    int steps = 0;
    BigInteger number = new BigInteger((input + "")); 
    if(isPalendrome(number)) printResult(input, steps, number);

    while(!isPalendrome(number)){
        String numberString = number.toString();
        String reversed = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < numberString.length(); i++){
            reversed += numberString.charAt(numberString.length() - 1 - i);
        }
        BigInteger numReversed = new BigInteger(reversed);
        number.add(numReversed);
        steps++;
    }

    printResult(input, steps, number);
}

public static void printResult(int number, int steps, BigInteger palendrome){
        System.out.printf("The number %d becomes palendromic after %d steps, and becomes the number: %d%n", number, steps, palendrome);
        System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

Comment: This is one of the rare cases where it's best to use a string throughout.

Comment: What is the exact problem?

Comment: "After doing this Ive ran into some problems that Im not really sure of" - what problems? Also try to avoid `System.exit`, it makes code hard to follow. If necessary, throw an exception.

Answer (score 5):

Your code goes into infinite loop  `while(!isPalendrome(number))` because,

```
  number.add(numReversed);
```

this doesn't change the value of `number`. You need assign it back.

`number= number.add(numReversed);`